# Type script - angular : static injector error

Tags: angular, typescript, sockets, dependency-injection

Hi i am trying to use socket.io in my angular project.
there are three files which i am going to show which are component file and one service file and one module file. when ever i use service in my component file i get the static injector error.
which is:

> Error: StaticInjectorError(AppModule)[AppComponent -> WrappedSocket]: 
>   StaticInjectorError(Platform: core)[AppComponent -> WrappedSocket]:
>   NullInjectorError: No provider for WrappedSocket!

**Here is the Component file:**

```
import { Component } from '@angular/core';   
import {  cheema2 } from './practice.service';
import { Injectable } from '@angular/core';
import { Socket } from 'ng-socket-io';

@Component
({
  selector: 'app-root',
  templateUrl: './app.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./app.component.css']
})

 @Injectable()    
 export class AppComponent  
 {   
     constructor(private socket: Socket) { }

     sendMessage(msg: string){
     this.socket.emit("message", msg);
   }

   getMessage() 
   {
     console.log( this.socket.fromEvent("message"));
   }

}
```

**Here is the Module file**

```
import { BrowserModule } from '@angular/platform-browser';   
import { NgModule } from '@angular/core';
import { SocketIoModule, SocketIoConfig } from 'ng-socket-io';

const config: SocketIoConfig = { url: 'http://localhost:4200', options: {}    
};       
import { AppComponent } from './app.component';

@NgModule
({  
declarations:
 [
   AppComponent
 ],
 imports: [
   BrowserModule
  ],
 providers: [],
 bootstrap: [AppComponent]
})

export class AppModule { }
```

**Here is the service file**

```
import { Injectable } from '@angular/core';  
import { Socket } from 'ng-socket-io';

@Injectable()
export class cheema2  
{
    constructor(private socket: Socket) { console.log("adil"); }

    sendMessage(msg: string){
       console.log("sharif");
       this.socket.emit("message", msg);
    }

    getMessage() {
      console.log( this.socket.fromEvent("message"));              
    }
}
```

any one who can solve this error.

Comment: Please reformat your code. Remove the empty lines and indent the code with 4 spaces

Comment: Hey there and welcome to StackOverflow! Please try to format your code, it helps the people to read and understand your problem and increases the probability of someone answering you.

https://meta.stackexchange.com/help/formatting

Answer (score 13, accepted):

You're missing an import in your AppModule:

```
import { BrowserModule } from '@angular/platform-browser';
import { NgModule } from '@angular/core';
import { SocketIoModule, SocketIoConfig } from 'ng-socket-io';
const config: SocketIoConfig = { 
  url: 'http://localhost:4200', options: {}
};

import { AppComponent } from './app.component';

@NgModule ({
  declarations: [
    AppComponent
  ],
  imports: [
    BrowserModule,
    SocketIoModule.forRoot(config) <<< ADD THIS
  ],
  providers: [],
  bootstrap: [AppComponent] })
export class AppModule { }
```